# What files need to be deleted before duplicating a VM?

Tags: system-installation

If you are going to duplicate a VM, what files should be deleted first?

For example, ssh keys should most likely be regenerated

```
rm -i /etc/ssh/ssh_host_{dsa,rsa,ecdsa}_key*
```

What other files should be removed?

**Update**

Assuming Ubuntu or CentOS server

**Update2**

Found the following clean script, it is missing a lot of things, but at least has an example of cleaning udev rules https://github.com/riywo/packer-example/blob/master/scripts/cleanup.sh

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: The clean script is only for Ubuntu (not RHEL/CentOS) and pretty much just clear DHCP leases and the persistent net rules (so that network device names are re-used for the new system). There's probably more to do if you wanted to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

1. All user home directories. Nuke it.
2. Clear the command history for root.
3. Clean out /var/log.
4. Any sensitive networking information.
5. Any configuration files for programs on the box that contains personal information.
6. Any paid programs, movies, or music.
7. Any browser data.

Edit: for servers specifically:

1. Any httpd files that shouldn't be served by the server (.htaccess, any httpd.conf information, script files)
2. Any SSL certificates should be deleted.
3. Hostname should be changed.
4. All "server services" (FTP, httpd, etc) should be disabled.

Comment: On RHEL6+ systems `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` should be truncated prior to the clone since the new VM will have a different MAC address. After the clone the contents should probably be put back (since they _are_ valid for this one machine).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a blog article that covers](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/03/26/preparing-linux-template-vms/) many operations for preparing a VM for cloning including:

- Stop logging services
- Remove old kernels
- clean yum / apt-get cache
- Rotate logs
- Audit Logs
- udev persistent devices
- Mac Address & UUID
- /tmp
- host ssh keys
- root user ssh keys
- bash history

The author then recommends zeroing out empty space and resizing the LVM Goup